# Cleaner approach for quetly closing multiple resources in Scala

Tags: scala

I am having multiple resources and I want to quietly close them in the finally block.

Following is the current approach that I am using. Is there any better (preferably a more concise and readable) approach to achieve the same?

I am also looking for some cleaner way to eliminate the use of `var` for storing resources.

```
    var connection1 = getConnection()
    var connection2 = getConnection()
    try {
      // do stuff
    } finally {
      try {
        if (connection1 != null) connection1.close()
      } catch {
        case NonFatal(_) => // log exception
      }
      try {
        if (connection2 != null) connection2.close()
      } catch {
        case NonFatal(_) => // log exception
      }
    }
```

Edit: I know that I can keep a collection of resources and loop over them to close them making the code concise. However, I am curious whether there is some better scala construct to make it more concise.

Comment: You may also want to give a look to `Resource` from **cats-effect** or `ZManaged` from **ZIO**.

Answer (score 5):

With Scala 2.13 it is quite nice:

```
import scala.util.Using
import java.io.{FileReader, FileWriter}
Using.resources(
  new FileReader("input.txt"), 
  new FileWriter("output.txt")) { (reader, writer) => 
    ???
}
```

This will do all the work for you.

I found this here: [my-favorite-new-features-of-scala-2-13](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/my-favorite-new-features-of-scala-2-13-standard-library-909a89b0da4)

There is also a link if you cannot use 2.13: [scala-try-with-resources](https://medium.com/@dkomanov/scala-try-with-resources-735baad0fd7d)